# ¿Cómo sacar números no repetidos de un array y almacenarlos en otro?

Tags: java, array, random

Muy buenas, mi pregunta es como se podría hacer para que a partir de dos arrays que tengan 10 números random sacar los que faltan es decir si me sale esto 1,2,4,5,7,0,8,8,0 que me saque los que falta 3,6,9 lo mismo con el segundo array y los numeros que falten no pueden repetirse entre si es decir si del primer array los numeros que faltan son estos 3,6,9 y del segundo estos porejemplo 3,2,5 meterlos en un 3 arrays pero sin que el 3 se repita, solo me falta el ultimo paso os agradeceria muchisimo la ayuda.

```
public class pruebas {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

      int[] aleatoris=new int[10];
      int[] aleatoris2=new int[10];
        int[] referencia = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        int[]resultat;
        int temp = -1;
        int temp2= -1;

            Random rand=new Random();

            int pos=0, num, num2;

            while(pos<aleatoris.length){
                num=rand.nextInt(10);
                num2=rand.nextInt(10);


                    aleatoris[pos++]=num;
                    aleatoris2[pos++]=num2;



                    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultat));


            }
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aleatoris));
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aleatoris2));

          for (int i =0;i<referencia.length;i++){
              for(int j =0;j<aleatoris.length;j++){
                  if ( aleatoris[j] == referencia[i]){
                      temp = -1;
                      break;
                  } else{
                      temp = referencia[i];

                  }

                  ;
              }
           if (temp != -1){
              System.out.print(temp+" ");

          }

          }
         for (int i=0;i<referencia.length;i++){
             for (int j = 0;j<aleatoris2.length;j++){
                 if ( aleatoris2[j] == referencia[i]){
                      temp2 = -1;
                      break;
                  } else{
                      temp2 = referencia[i];
                  }
              }
           if (temp2 != -1){
              System.out.print(temp2+" ");




              }




              }





        /* for (int i=0;i < referencia.length;i++){
             for (int j=0; j < referencia.length;j++){


             }
             }*/
         }

         }
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. ¿Quieres crear un tercer array que contenga 2,3,5,6,9 según el ejemplo que dices?

Comment: Que estructuras de datos puedes utilizar? Solo arreglos?. Por cierto estas llenando mal los arreglos de aleatorios, estas saltandote posiciones, mejor ocupa un `for` aumentando solo una vez el indice `pos`

Comment: Hola @cronimo65, esto es una tarea? Porque la respuesta puede variar si lo es o no.

Comment: un tercer o los que haya falta pero para que tengas una idea tiene que ser algo parecido a esto: array1 {0,1,2,4,5,5,6,7,8} array2{0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,} de estos sacar los que faltan que serian del array1 faltaria el numero 3 del array2 el 8 y almacenarlos en otra array el problema esque los numeros tienen que ser random y al sacar los que faltan si tanto en el array1 y el array2 falta 3 que no se repita 2 veces en el array donde guardaremos los numeros que falten en mi caso yo le puse el nombre de resultat

Comment: Klaimmore tiene que ser con arreglos es una actividad que si la hago bien me saco el primer trimestre, si tienes razon de hecho la variable pos se podria quitar.

Comment: Como es una actividad no quiero ponerte el código resuelto, ya que no ayudaría en mucho. Lo mas sencillo seria que hicieses un array de booleanos de 10 posiciones `boolean[] aparece = new boolean[10];` y si aparece por ejemplo el 3 pongas esa posicion a true `aparece[3] = true`. Y luego al final recorres ese array con un for de 0 a a 9 y si `aparece[i]`es igual a true lo metes en el array resultat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resuelto tu problema desde el principio en modo verboso, bien explicado y detallado. Si tienes algún problema o no entiendes algo ponlo en los comentarios.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
    /*
     * Autor: Trewqa
     * Para StackOverflow (145120)
     * 
     * Sacar en un Array los números que no se encuentren en otros dos arrays.
     */


    //Declaramos una constante para definir el tamaño de los array.
    public static final int ARRAY_TAM = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] aleatorio1 = new int[ARRAY_TAM];
        int[] aleatorio2 = new int[ARRAY_TAM];

        int[] aux = new int[10]; //Lo inicializamos a 10 posiciones, tantas como números (0..9)
        int numfaltan = 0; //Esta variable nos dirá cuántos números nos faltan


        //Metenmos valores aleatorios a los arrays
        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_TAM; i++)
        {
            //Con (int)Math.random()*9 obtenemos un número entero aleatorio de 0 a 9

            aleatorio1[i] = (int)(Math.random()*9);
            aleatorio2[i] = (int)(Math.random()*9);
        }

        //Imprimimos los arrays
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aleatorio1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aleatorio2));


        /*
         * Aquí viene el bucle con el que sacaremos que números no están en ambos arrays.
         * Usaremos el array aux en el que usaremos sus posiciones como los números, esto es, la posicion 0 representa al 0, la 9 representa al 9...
         * 
         * Daremos valor -1 (por defecto) si no está el número en el array y lo cambiaremos por otro valor si está en alguno de los otros dos arrays.
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            //Inicializamos la posición i = -1 (Como que ese número no lo tenemos)
            aux[i] = -1;

            for (int j = 0; j < ARRAY_TAM; j++)
            {
                if (aleatorio1[j] == i || aleatorio2[j] == i)
                {
                    //Si el número i está en alguno de los arrays, le cambiamos el -1 por otra cosa, por ejemplo un 0, para saber que lo tenemos.
                    aux[i] = 0;
                }
            }

            if (aux[i] == -1)
            {
                //Si el número no lo tenemos sumamos 1 a la variable que declaramos al principio.
                numfaltan++;
            }
        }

        //Ya sabemos cuantos números nos faltan, los contamos en numfaltan
        System.out.format("Nos faltan %d número(s)", numfaltan);

        //Hacemos un vector para almacenar los números que nos faltan
        int[] faltan = new int[numfaltan];
        int posicion = 0;//Lo usamos para saber la posición en la que insertar los números que nos faltan

        //Recorremos el array auxiliar que nos dirá los números que faltan
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (aux[i] == -1)
            {
                //Si falta este número, que corresponde a su posición, lo metemos en el array faltan
                faltan[posicion++] = i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(faltan));

    }

}
```

Comment: es justo lo que necesitaba de esta forma se entiende bastante mejor gracias.

Comment: @cronimo65 recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada, dándole al tick verde a la izquierda.